# Free navigation app that allows me to specify my speed on different road types

Tags: maps, openstreetmap, navigation, car, google-maps

Are there any free navigation apps that allows me to specify my speed on different road types? I want to, as far as it is reasonable, avoid to drive on certain road types. A good way to accomplish that is to set the speed to an artificially low value. Co-Pilot offers this functionality but it is not free and I would use it very rarely (a few times a year).

Edit: Another example of navigation software that allowed the user to specify the speed was the desktop version of Route 66.

Comment: Co-pilot is also not cheap (GBP 100 for Android). Would you be willing to pay less? If so, do you have a feel? Ten GBP/EUR/USD? Twenty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using Co-Pilot in demo mode for this purpose for a while now and although this solution requires some manual work it works pretty well. I have set the motorway speed to 60-70 km/h and with that setting I mostly avoid motorways and instead am directed to drive single lane roads with a speed limits in the region of 70-100 km/h - which was exactly what I aimed at.

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps allows you to do this by setting road types you would rather avoid or by using "alternate route" methods.

> To change a driving route, click and hold a spot on the route and drag it to a new spot on the map. If you're using Maps in Lite mode, you won't be able to drag to change routes.

Basically you let it plot your route then just drag around the area you want to avoid.

[Example of changing route](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8x5vfuphg2eis7s/out.ogv?dl=0)

In this example I went home my home to a local business and avoided a "traffic" area around the stadium and community collage.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to do it the other way around: I want the map software to suggest a road rather than me manually adjusting the road.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure about an app that allows you to specify your speed on different road types but from former experience using ***The Field Trip app*** (by Google) where it looks for sites of interest around you,allows you to mention certain road types(i'm not sure i just heard it from someone).
it's not much of an answer but i'll find out more and inform you when i can